# always get "libmobile_vision_face.so library load status: false"

Tags: android, android-vision

I've created an application based on this example and found an issue while testing my application.  it usually work on my testing devices but not on user's devices.

I've tried to google for the solution but nothing solved this.

Could anyone help?

Thank you,
 Big.

**Tested on Android version**: 6.0.1, 7.x,

**Google Play Service version**: >= 12

**Internet Connection**: Yes

Trace:

```
...
04-24 19:59:54.082 26109-27099/com.beid W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
04-24 19:59:54.100 26109-27099/com.beid I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1702
04-24 19:59:54.100 26109-27099/com.beid I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1702
04-24 19:59:54.113 26109-27099/com.beid I/Vision: Loading library libmobile_vision_face.so
04-24 19:59:54.113 26109-27099/com.beid I/Vision: libmobile_vision_face.so library load status: false
...
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="...">
...
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<application android:name="....">
  ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="ocr,face" />
  ...
</application>
```

Build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
...
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.0"
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this it's work with me

clear all data app> google play service and clear all data

and add this in AndroidManifest.xml

I found solution i clear all data in app>google play service

And add this in AndroidMnifest.xml

Try this

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
    android:value="face" />
```